# How to get a matched word, not a line

Tags: regex, shell

We can use grep to return the lines with matched words, but how to only return the words?
say there is:

```
The original MC68000 was fabricated using
```

how to return     `MC68000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a frequently asked question. GNU grep has the `-o` for this (show the match `only` not the entire line). This is not described in The Single Unix Specification.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what he was asking. I understood He wants to return the 3 field, not filter by it.

Comment: It seems clear, e.g. `grep -E -o 'MC68[0-9]+'` will match that `MC68000` and show only that, not the whole line. Looks like demaxSH accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed:

```
grep "myword" myfile | sed "s/.*\(myword\).*/\1/"
```

Comment: This is the most standard-conforming answer since it doesn't rely on GNU extensions. But it's somewhat of a useless use of `grep` since you can do it all in sed: `sed -n -e 's/.*\(myword\).*/\1/' -e '/myword/p'`.  The `-n` stops sed from echoing every line, so then you use `p` to print what you want (the last letter of "grep").